# Codewars problem: "NASM: Does this string contain numbers?" Not sure why my code is failing with specific tests

Tags: string, assembly, x86-64, nasm, cpu-registers

I am trying to check whether a string contains digits, this code works for test cases:

expected output : input

> 0 : "This is sample test!"
> 0 : "I've just turned five!"
> 1 : "My favourite number is: 1337"
> 0 : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. This text has no numbers!"
> 1 : "0"

But for a reason unknown to me, it fails on all of these tests in should_work_for_more_fixed_assertions:

> "I <3 NASM"
> "The NASM/C environment in Codewars does not use CW-2 as its  testing framework."
> "Hello W0rld!"
> "Hello Wor1d!"
> "H2llo World!"
> "H3llo World!"
> "Hello4World!"
> ...
> etc.

Here is my code:

```
global has_digits
section .text
has_digits:

  cmp rdi, 0            ; string
  je end                ; null pointer
  
  xor ax, ax            ; result = 0
  xor cx, cx            ; char = 0
  xor rsi, rsi          ; index = 0
  
  dec rsi               ; index--
  while:
    inc rsi             ; index++
    mov cx, [rdi+rsi]   ; char = string[index]
    
    cmp cx, 0           ; if char == 0:
    je end              ; break
    
    cmp cx, 48          ; if char < '0':
    jl while            ; continue
    
    cmp cx, 57          ; if char > '9':
    jg while            ; continue
    
    mov ax, 1           ; result = true
  
  end:
    ret                 ; return
```

It would be great if you could tell me what I am doing wrong, without giving a full solution, but any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: `cx` is a 16-bit word register. Use `cl` if your text is encoded as 8-bit ASCII (or UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks, I was having a play with this and h registers worked for alot of the tests but to get all of them I had to switch to l ones, do you know why that might be?

Comment: No, I would need to see examples to figure that out. `ch` should work too if you replaced all uses of `cx` in the question's code by `ch`.

Comment: @ecm This example might be based on some Windows code, where the string is encoded in UTF-16 (two bytes per character).  OP would then need to double instructions `dec rsi` and `inc rsi`. In that case using `cx` would be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not sure why my code is failing with specific tests

Let us turn that around and find out why 2 tests do report having found a number.

> 1 : "My favourite number is: 1337"
> 1 : "0"

When your instruction `mov cx, [rdi+rsi] ; char = string[index]` supposedly retrieves a single character in the CL register, it also retrieves the following byte in the CH register. For the 2 strings that do report having found a number, it is the very last character in the string that is a digit and that effectively is followed by the zero-terminator byte, and hence processing CX instead of CL didn't pose a problem. **The solution therefore is to read but a single byte from the string memory**. Use the `movzx ecx, byte [rdi+rsi]` instruction that zero-extends the byte into the full RCX register for maximum efficiency.

> It would be great if you could tell me what I am doing wrong, without giving a full solution

It's hardly a full solution this next code snippet:

```
; IN (rdi) OUT (rax) MOD (rcx,rdi)
has_digits:
  xor   eax, eax        ; RAX:= false
  sub   rdi, 1
  jb    .end            ; null pointer
.while:
  inc   rdi             ; index++
  movzx ecx, byte [rdi] ; char = string[index]
  test  ecx, ecx        ; if char == 0:
  jz    end             ; break
  sub   ecx, '0'
  cmp   ecx, 9          ; Anything outside of [0,9] is not a digit
  ja    .while
  inc   eax             ; RAX:= true, RCX=[0,9] (first digit found)
.end:
  ret
```

Comment: Thanks for this, can I also ask. I see alot of people use a dot before their labels as you have done here but it has not seemed to make a difference for my use cases. So why is it done?

Comment: @MultipleSources The labels that start with a dot are so-called *local* labels. They are valid between any two normal aka *global* labels. The global labels all need to have unique names wherever they're used, but the local labels only need to be uniquely named within their scope (so the lines between any two global labels). In short: you as a programmer need to spend less time coming up with meaningful names for all the labels in your program.